# socket.io multiple chats on one page

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat, chatroom

I want to implement multiple chat windows on one page (like facebook for e.g.).
Currently using "rooms", simplified code:

**[client]**

```
socket.emit('join', 'room1');
socket.emit('join', 'room2');
```

**[server]**

```
socket.on('join', function(room)
{
    socket.join(room);
});
```

so each separate room on client, it is a separate class that handles the chat logic, it must receive events from server only for connected room. But if it is one page, then one socket connection used, so if one socket will connect to multiple rooms, then subscribing to one room, will also receive events from another room. How should I separate this?

I'm thinking about these ways:

1. Force new socket connection for each room (so 10 chats = 10 sockets), I think it is not good idea, because of highload (if I'm not right, please correct me)
2. Prefix for client events, e.g if I want to handle events for specific room I will subscribe like this:

**[client]**

```
var room = 'room1';
socket.on(room + '.new_message', function()
{
    // append message to chat
});
```

**[server]**

```
io.sockets.in('room1').emit('room1.new_message', 'some message');
```

is this a good idea?

If it is other ways to do it, please share with me.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I'm trying to do the same

Comment: check out `namespacing` http://socket.io/docs/#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace

Answer (score 0):

One socket one room, no problem about having multiple sockets on.

Answer (score -1):

I think you only create one socket to connect to server. But one socket can join multi room. 
When server send to client, you must determine room send.
example: socket.broadcast.to(room).emit(.....{data: idRoom});.
When client receive socket from server. it must determine popUp will receive message. You can use idRoom from Server to determine PopUp receive.
Sorry for my English