# Socket.io chat mulitple posts after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Building a chat with socket.io, I came along with a bug that seems to me elementary, but I cannot find an answer.

#### The number of posted messages after refreshing page is the same with page refreshes (I post only one each time).

I checked similar answers like 
[socket-io-multiple-chats-on-one-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411481/socket-io-multiple-chats-on-one-page)
[socket-io-multiple-connections-when-refreshing-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083104/socket-io-multiple-connections-when-refreshing-page)
[node-js-socket-io-page-refresh-multiple-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924713/node-js-socket-io-page-refresh-multiple-connections)
The main difference with the above is that the count of connected sockets in console is correct.
I also tried the solution of [node-js-socket-io-page-refresh-multiple-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924713/node-js-socket-io-page-refresh-multiple-connections)

```
var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
```

but no result. I also tried rooms and namespaces.

[image]
Tested on Chrome 72, Canary 74.

#### Here's part of my server

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('subscribe', function(data) { socket.join(room); })
 socket.on('unsubscribe', function(data) { socket.leave(room); })
        socket.on("newchatsent", function (msg) {
        //save chat to mongo
        MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('An error occurred connecting to MongoDB: ', err);
            } else {
                var db = client.db(database);
                var collection = db.collection("chat");
                collection.updateOne({"cid": cid},{
                        $push: {"chat": {u: who, c: msg, t: timestamp}},
                        "$inc": {"total": 1}, "$inc": {[unread]: 1}
                    }, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            //emit data to frontend
                            socket.emit("newchatreply", msg);
                            client.close();
                        }
                        assert.equal(err, null);
                    });
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

#### And here is a part of client

```
var socket = io({transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
socket.emit("subscribe", room);

    $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13 && $("#chatText").is(":focus")) {
            var mes = $('#chatText').val().trim();
            if (mes != "") {
                socket.emit('newchatsent', mes);
                $('#chatText').val('');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

socket.on('newchatreply', function(msg){
    $( "#chati" ).append( "<div id='chatLine'><p class='triangle-isosceles right'>"+ msg +"</p>" +
        "<div class='chatDatetime'>"+date('Y-m-d H:i')+"</div></div>");
});
```

#### No case of preventing refresh - the chatbox has to be open through multiple pages. Any thoughts?

### Solution

Given by [Sriram Kailasam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6120848/sriram-kailasam): The problem is that you are registering a new event handler every time the page is reloaded. This causes the data to be sent multiple times. I had the same issue and I solved by using `io.once()` instead of `io.on()` in the server.

Comment: Looks like delays , i don't see nothing abnormal in code. Are y running this on public or in local ? What about reconnections?

Comment: public with ssl, Nikola. Reconnections seems to be ok, 1 socket disconnects, 1 socket reconnects,number not increasing.

Comment: Socket.io disconnect and reconnect again when the user reload the html pages.  In my previous chat App, I use a single 'parent' html file, i.e. the index.html.  There is a divContent inside this html file and I use Jquery .load function to load other pages into this divContent, to avoid the page reload, which means that the disconnect event never fires unless the user close the browser or the App (I'm using Cordova)

Comment: yes, less refreshing is better in general, but it's always a case.